# Stream from external source using iframe with sandbox tag?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iframe, stream

I am trying to show the stream from an external site. That site has too many pop-up ads, and I am trying to block pop-up using the sandbox attribute. But it is showing

> **Remove sandbox attributes on the iframe tag**

How can I solve it?

removing the sandbox fixes the issue, but there are a lot of pop-ups.

Here is the code I am using.

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="true" 
    referrerpolicy="same-origin"
    sandbox="allow-form allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
    frameborder="0" height="540" scrolling="no" src="https://somesrc.com/11.php" 
    width="780"
>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did u find a fix?